# Unit testing serial port in java

Tags: java, junit, serial-port, jssc

I have a program that is communicating with a hardware serial port sensor.
I use jssc as a connection abstraction library.

I would like to crate a virtual serial port test class I can use to test my real production code without a hardware sensor.

How do I mock/fake/virtualise a serial port in unit tests?
Can it be done in java?

Comment: You can develop a layer for abstract jssc library and mock it to test your production code, instead of make a real connection

Comment: yes, that is one option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using something like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) to mock the external library.